# How to show images from imagelist random in labels

Tags: c#

I have to make a memorygame.
MSDN has already a tutorial about it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/dd553235.aspx

But thats with wingdings, and i would make it with my own images.
So my question is: how could i show images from an imagelist randomly in labels?

I have already tried different things but with no result. This is one of te ways i have tried to make a imagelist but i don't know how to place it randomly in labels, who are inside a TableLayoutPanel.

[image]

Comment: when you want to change the images?

Comment: @Sia: That is actually not how a memory game works ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The icons the tutorial uses are strings. They can be shown in a label control. But yours are images. You might consider using picture box control.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
 iconLabel.Text = icons[randomNumber];
```

with

```
 iconLabel.Tag = randomNumber;
```

This stores the number of each card in its `Tag` property, a multi-purpose field.

Also set the size of the `Label`, and turn off `AutoSize` :

```
iconLabel.Size = yourImageList.ImageSize;
iconLabel.AutoSize = false;
```

Don't forget to set `yourImageList.ImageSize` and `yourImageList.ColorDepth` to values you like **before** loading the Images into the list!

Also: Instead of turning the `ForegroundColor` to `Black` when hiding them set the `Image` to null :

```
iconLabel.Image = null;
```

and when showing it use the `Tag` where you have stored the number to retrieve the image:

```
iconLabel.Image = yourImageList.Images[(int)iconLabel.Tag];
```

You could also add an extra image to the list that shows a nice pattern as the background of each card and set it as the image initially and when hiding..

To make its size flexible you can also replace the `Labels` with `Panels` and use the `Panel.BackgroundImage`. Then you can set the `Panel` to any size and chose e.g. `BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch`